# Reveal a UIView behind a UIWebview while scrolling to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I have a web page where in user can read some information/details ("webDetailsView"). I have a few actions based on the details on the page, like **"Comment"**, **"Submit"**, **"Claim"** etc. ("actionView").

The webpage is displayed in a `UIWebview`, say "webDetailsView". The action items are in a `UIView` - Say "actionView". These two views are in a component view (a `UIView` not a `UIScrollView`).

Now I want to reveal the "actionView" on swipe-down-gesture or scroll-down of "webDetailsView"
much like that pull-to-refresh view. How do I achieve this?

Explained in the "[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PpNS.png)".

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to detect touches and gesture (e.g. pull down) on a UIWebView, beacuse it will cause a terrible user experience and bad user interaction with the uiwebview itself.
Try using a normal UView instead of UIWebView.

Comment: Cause of an unfortunate reason I can't change it to UIView. Thank you for the advice though!